# E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'GetProcAddress' that can be called with these arguments

Tags: delphi, dll

I created dynamic Dll and i was using a method of this DLL in my Delphi Appliction.
Iam getting these errors, can't really figure out whats the reason.

I declared the method like this

```
TWithdrawMoney = function(currentBalance,withdrawBalance:double):double;stdcall;
```

and used it as

```
Handle := LoadLibrary('C:\Projects\WithdrawMoneyDLL.dll');   //Line 83
 if (currentBalance > 0) and (strtofloat(money.Text) <= currentBalance) then
    begin
            if Handle <> 0 then    //Line 96
            begin
              @withdrawMoney := GetProcAddress(Handle, 'withdrawMoney');    //line 98
              currentBalance := withdrawMoney(currentBalance,strtofloat(money.Text));
            end;
      ShowMessage('Widraw successful');
    end
```

these are the errors that I am are getting.

```
[dcc32 Error] widrawMoneyPanel.pas(83): E2129 Cannot assign to a read-only property
[dcc32 Error] widrawMoneyPanel.pas(96): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
[dcc32 Error] widrawMoneyPanel.pas(98): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'GetProcAddress' that can be called with these arguments
[dcc32 Fatal Error] F2063 Could not compile used unit 'widrawMoneyPanel.pas'
```

Comment: You should fix errors one by one, starting with the first, not the last. And when you fix the first one, the last one may even disappear by itself. So, how declared variable `Handle`?

Comment: @Zed, yes you are right, i should be fixing errors from first.this is how i declared handle. Handle:THandle;

Comment: Try change variable name to VHandle, because Handle may be the name of property `Form.Handle` or `Application.Handle`.

Comment: That worked @zed, Thanks...Now im only getting one error. ` E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'GetProcAddress' that can be called with these arguments `

Comment: Follow this example: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Libraries_and_Packages_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Loading

Comment: You used the wrong type for the module handle. It should be HModule.